# radio button and storing its value to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to asssign the return value from a script function to a javascript variable inside the html body???
this will return selected variable so how can i assign it to variable inside my html body

```
<body>
<form action="somepage.php" method="post" >
            <table cellpadding=50px>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="opt1" id="op1"></input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="opt2" id="op2"></input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="opt3" id="op3"></input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="option" value="opt4" id="op4"></input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button"  name="click" value="Click" onclick="get_value()">
            <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
<script>
            function get_value() {
                var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
                    if (x[i].checked==true) {
                        selected=x[i].value;
                        return selected;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: did you mean you can give javascript value assign into php so it can not possible.

Comment: Why do you need JS to return selected in your case?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to understand how things work together before starting to code stuff.

- Web browser requests a PHP file to a server.
- The file is first executed by PHP (ON SERVER-SIDE) which turns it into an HTML piece free of any PHP code
- The generated text (that may eventually contain javascript or css) is then sent back to the browser.
- Finally the browser parses it (ON CLIENT-SIDE) to turn it into an element tree, and also parses and executes pieces of javascript and css eventually contained in the HTML.

There is no way to put a return value of javascript into PHP because PHP is executed before javascript, and separatly.

And since you're not using HTML5, a script is declared this way :

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: then how to get the clicked value in that somepage.php

Comment: You use google with the right keywords (radio, button, php, value) and in less than one minute you find : http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_to_send_a_radio_button_variable_in_PHP